# flash as3 function calculation return character instead of blank

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have created a formula sheet, with basically 1 input field which will return 4 results, and a calculate button.
on a right input, right results, which i have no problem.
on a blank input, the results should remain blank with error message at the bottom. but right now the results somehow returned a "a", and the calculate button does not work when the right input is in. my codes' below, appreciate advice.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

calculate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,calculateClick);
var inputNum:String;
var tRes:Number;
var mRes: Number;
var sRes: Number;
function calculateClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if (inputNum != ""){
    inputNum = inputTxt.text;
    tRes = Math.round((parseInt(inputNum) * 10000 / 3600)*10)/10;
    tRes.toString();
    tCal.text = String(tRes);
    mRes = tRes * 20;
    mCal.text = String(mRes);
    sRes = mRes - 556;
    sCal.text = String(sRes);
    } else if (inputNum == "") {
    tCal.text = "";
    mCal.text = "";
    sCal.text = "";
    warningTxt.text = "Error! Please input!";

    }
}
```

Comment: It's tough to recreate this since I don't know the whole setup or what manPowerRes is. Is the "A" lower case? If so you might be seeing part of NaN for a bad math calculation. Could you provide any more info?

Comment: hello andrew, i edited the above code. manPowerRes is actually mRes which i forgot to update here. 
it is a small "a", and it appears only when i did not enter anything into inputTxt, and the error will only appear when i click the Calculate button again. then the button ceases its original function no matter what i enter after the error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I have it working. I did change the calc on the line "tRes = Math.round(inputNum * 10000 / 3600)" but you should be able to change it back to what you had without any problems.

```
calculate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,calculateClick);
var inputNum:Number;
var tRes:Number;
var mRes: Number;
var sRes: Number;
function calculateClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    inputNum = Number(inputTxt.text);
    if (!isNaN(inputNum)){
        tRes = Math.round(inputNum * 10000 / 3600)
        tCal.text = String(tRes);
        mRes = tRes * 20;
        mCal.text = String(mRes);
        sRes = mRes - 556;
        sCal.text = String(sRes);
        warningTxt.text = "";
    } else {
        tCal.text = "";
        mCal.text = "";
        sCal.text = "";
        warningTxt.text = "Error! Please input!";
    }
}
```

Comment: hello andrew, thanks for your suggestion!
i tried and it works, except that the error doesnt appear now when i leave the input field blank..

Comment: hello andrew, i tried removing !isNaN and its working to what i think i needed. thanks alot, you're a great help!!